# Can anyone explain this paragraph of the current C++0x standard draft?

Tags: c++, scope, c++11, standards

Can anyone explain this statement from ISO N3242 §3.3.3, 2nd point

> The potential scope of a function parameter name ***(including one appearing in lambda-declarator) or of a function-local predefined variable*** in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration. If the function has a function-try-block the potential scope of a parameter ***or of a function-local predefined variable*** ends at the end of the last associated handler, otherwise it ends at the end of the outermost block of the function definition. A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a function-try-block.

ISO Standard 2003 says:

> The potential scope of a function parameter name in a function definition (8.4) begins at its point of declaration. If the function has a function-try-block the potential scope of a parameter ends at the end of the last associated handler, else it ends at the end of the outermost block of the function definition. A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a function-try-block.

What is the actual difference in these statements?

Any one explain the above added point in terms of example/program...?

I noticed that it belongs to **function-local predefined variable** what actually he is saying .. there ,regarding this ?

Comment: Did you look for "function-local predfined variable" in the referenced section 8.4?

Comment: This is your **sixth** version of "Can anyone explain this paragraph of the current C++0x standard draft?" What is gained by asking "spot the difference" questions, pasting two related paragraphs from two versions of the standard?

Comment: I see no problem in this form of question, but please give them unique titles.

Answer (score 4):

The changes are the addition of "function-local predefined variables", which are new to C++0x. They are implicitly defined static variables available for use within the function. The draft standard defines one called `__func__` which gives the name of the function, and allows implementations to add more of their own. This paragraph now says that they are available wherever the function parameter names are.